# How to Optimized Images in C# Without Loosing Its Size and Quality using jpegoptim.exe

Tags: c#-4.0, image-processing, image-size

I want to optimized images without Loosing its quality and dimension in Asp.net using C# by the help of `jpegoptim.exe` tool

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you would like to optimize an image with the help of that toolset. However, hereby I would like to addon - why don't you explore other options as well.

I know this might not be a best answer but hope [this](http://www.encodedna.com/2014/07/how-to-resize-an-image-using-aspdotnet-without-losing-quality.htm) link helps you to where you might wish to go.

Ask if anything.